# Lex/Flex - Scanning for the EOF character

Tags: bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

Other people have had the following problem that I am having but I can't find anyone that has reported a solution.. getting Flex to spot the EOF (end of file).  I need Flex to find EOF and return a token indicating that it has found it so it can tell Yacc/Bison that it has reached the end of an input source file and can report a successful parse.

Note that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854826/how-to-detect-eof-in-ml-lex) is not the same as this one because this is about Lex/Flex.

Any help would be awesome.  Thank you.

Comment: Something wrong here. You normally don't need to do this. Just write a target symbol into your grammar and it's all taken care of.

Comment: @EJP: Could you please make a little example? I am a newbie in Flex/Bison. How to achieve this as a simple grammar rule? Thankyou

Comment: @EJP, when entering from a real keyboard, Ctrl-Z is passed to the program, causing a syntax error. I am unable to catch it using things like /x1a but <<EOF>> works.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Flex has
[`<<EOF>>`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html)
pattern which matches only end-of-file.
Probably you can return some token indicating end-of-file to the parser
as the following.

```
<<EOF>>     return END_OF_FILE;
```